# Leetcode C program, two numbers in array that add to target

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a Leetcode problem using C, and for some reason the Output of my program is showing an empty array. The challenge is to write a function that returns an array consisting of the indices of two numbers in an array that sum to a target number. I solved it with Python, but now I am trying to solve it with C. What am I missing? Does it have something to do with returnSize?

Note: The constraints say there will be only one answer (two numbers that add up to the target) in each array for each target.

The solution I have tried is as follows:

```
/**
* Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
*/
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int* answer;
    answer = malloc(2*sizeof(int));

    // Success flag flips when two ints are identified
    bool success = false;

    // Look through every element of nums
    for(int first_number = 0; first_number < numsSize; first_number++)
    {
        // If index is at end of array, do not check further.
        if(first_number < numsSize)
        {
            // For each number in array, look at all of the numbers after it
            for(int second_number=(first_number + 1); second_number < numsSize; second_number++)
            {
                if((nums[first_number] + nums[second_number] == target))
                {
                    answer[0] = first_number;
                    answer[1] = second_number;
                    // Flip success flag
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Check success flag and break. No need to check further.
        if(success){
            break;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

**Update**
Answered by Fe2O3. Thank you. If anyone comes across this post, read Fe2O3's answer. WhozCraig also gives a good explanation of the problem. It turns out `int *returnSize` is a pointer to a variable that stores the size of the output array. I guess the size of dynamically allocated arrays can't be determined as easily as statically allocated arrays (e.g. `int returnSize[2]`). Fe2O3 also has some good things to say about the implementation of the Leetcode answer and not limiting oneself to standard answers. He gave multiple solutions that work. I hope this helps.

Comment: One problem is definitely your formatting

Comment: Please explain.
Edit: This is my first post on Stackoverflow. If there is anything I can do better, I am open for feedback.

Comment: Ask yourself, "What would be the purpose of `int* returnSize` as a parameter?"

Comment: @Fe2O3 Ok. I set returnSize = 2, and it solved the problem. I'm still not sure what the purpose of returnSize is, though. Can you explain why it is necessary? Also, may I use your name in the update? I am new here, and I am not 100% on this forum's etiquette.

Comment: @JDCirbo It's the size of the dynamic array being returned by the function result value (array). Somehow that magnitude must be communicated to the caller.

Comment: Leetcode is a joke. Work through the chapters and exercises of a real book on C. You shouldn't `malloc()` the buffer until you find that you need it. So... If the array does NOT have two values that sum to the target, returning 0 says "no luck" and returning 2 says "made it." Functions can return ONE value. This function wants to return Two. (PS: Name away... No worries :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you so much for your help! I was completely unaware that malloc had that limitation. I thought you could just use a sizeof like with other arrays. Apparently, I know just enough C to blow my foot off! LOL! Other than the Denis Richie book, do you have any recommendations for C books? I stumbled upon Leetcode, and I had read that it might be a good idea to familiarize myself the site as some future interview might include some Leetcode problem. Is that just hype?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your explanation! I had no idea that was necessary when using dynamic arrays.

Comment: "Some future interview" may include anything. Keep writing code and experimenting with what works. (No point in trying to write "clever" code that only seems to work.) Learn "data structures". A willingness to learn is more important, imo, than a few memorised clever tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having bitten into this apple, I feel compelled to demonstrate how this function might be written by one with more experience:

```
int *twoSum( int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *returnSize ) {
    *returnSize = 0; // default

    for( int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++ )
        for( int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++ )
            if( nums[ i ] + nums[ j ] == target ) {
                int *answer = malloc( 2 * sizeof *answer );
                /* Omitting verification of malloc success for brevity */
                answer[0] = i;
                answer[1] = j;
                *returnSize = 2;
                return answer;
            }

    return NULL;
}
```

It's a silly (Leetcode) problem.
The caller should provide the array (could be stack instead of heap allocation) for the two indices (if found). The function would "know" it can write two integer indices into that array IF a pair is located. Then the function merely returns `true` or `false` as to whether it had success or not...

**EDIT**
Longer response to OP question below:

A minor change to the Leetcode problem might take this form. Notice that the "return array" exists on the stack in the function `main()` (without needing the heap allocation.) The function needs 4 parameters and returns true/false if it was able to put the two desired values into the 2 element array.

```
int main(){
    const int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 9 };
    const int arrSz = sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0];
    const int target = 4 + 9; // last two values
    int inds[2] = { 0 }; // ALWAYS initialise variables

    if( twoSum( arr, arrSz, target, inds ) )
        print( "[%d, %d]\n", inds[0], inds[1] );
    else
        print("Error\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Bothered by the OP reference to "future job interview questions", this answer needs to be revisited.

Below is a "general purpose" version of the function that disregards the "promise" that only one pair of array elements may satisfy the task. The following will grow the array being returned if multiple pairs are found.

Further, (and this is the "job interview" aspect), the solution should recognise that there was no restriction that each of any pair found had to be distinct. In other words, one element + its own value may be a legitimate solution. It is unwise to assume... This *sensitivity* and "thinking outside the box" is often what potential employers are seeking. It is the coder who thinks only "inside the box" who will introduce bugs into code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// 0 == allow arr[X] + arr[X] == target
// 1 == only distinct elements to be considered
#define ONLY_DIFF 1

int *twoSum( int *nums, int sz, int target, int *rs ) {
    // Begin with no pairs
    int *retArr = NULL;
    *rs = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < sz; i++ )
        for( int j = i + ONLY_DIFF; j < sz; j++ )
            if( nums[ i ] + nums[ j ] == target ) {
                int *hope = realloc( retArr, (*rs + 2) * sizeof *hope );
                if( hope == NULL ) {
                    fprintf( stderr, "realloc failure\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
                retArr = hope;
                *rs += 2;
                retArr[ *rs - 2 ] = i;
                retArr[ *rs - 1 ] = j;
            }

    return retArr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So, I don't know how Leetcode implemented the function, but it appears that it relies heavily on that returnSize pointer. If I am understanding you correctly, a better implementation would be something like this?

```
int main(){
    int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int b = 3;
    int c[2];
    int *d;
    c = twoSum(a, b, d);
    if(c)
        print("[%d, %d]\n", c[0], c[1]);
    else
        print("Error\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: re: "closed" - The judgments of SO moderators are not always explicable. re: "bothered" - "Entry level" positions should, imho, explore a candidate's aptitude and honesty; not ability to reproduce a solution to a problem found on a public website. Knowing the range of "Standard Library" functions enables one to use `qsort()` adeptly instead of struggling to re-code bubble sort... The jubilation of solving a Leetcode challenge with bad code can overshadow the benefit of learning how to code clearly & cleanly utilising proven library functions. You learn those from books/self study.

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry if I made a bigger deal out of the question being closed than it was. I am new here. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @JDCirbo imo, there is nothing about your question that should have it closed or DV'd... The only route forward is perseverance. My career experience is mirrored here in SO where those with power can/will wield it at whim... _Illegitimi non carborundum_ `:-)`

Comment: I appreciate that very much. I was actually feeling kind of stupid and wondering if I should just get off here before I make a huge fool out of myself, but you make a great point. I imagine that these experiences are rites of passage for those who are serious about joining the coding community. Thank you. I will, however, endeavor to read/study and research my issues more before posting on here. Also, I am going to dive into some C programming books and stop listening to Youtube videos about job interview questions. Lol.

Comment: May the force be with you... `:-)`